# Basics difference between distributed computing and interprocess communication?

Tags: distributed-computing, interprocess

I know the theritical definition for distributed computing and interproces communication.

But in real time I was not able to come to conclusion that when we go for distributed or interprocess.

Tell me some scenario where we can go for distributed computing or interprocess communication by example.

Comment: Interprocess communication (IPC) is a *method for implementing* distributed computing (there are others) but I'm not sure what this question is asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interprocess communication basically would mean comuniction b/t processes.

mostly this concept is used when studying parallel programming and studying the working of operating system.

this topic is to huge to explain, its a full subject, try googling interprocess communication and read the basic definations.

2)
my initial understanding is:-

imagine a office, why does it have several employees in one department? because many brains and men power is needed to bring one task to completion. one man can do the job but it might take days and what if he gets sick! so distributed...

now how to communicate between the porcesses/people doing there independent task of the job on different computers/different CPU's of the same computer/within different cabins of the same office building?

"shout!! hey i have done my work take the result and send more?? who is in charge here!! answer ****"

no right!

so here come the INTER PROCESS COMMUNICATION subject.

note:- please note i am also a learning person :-) so do not take the above as right without doing your own googling, i am not responsible for any .........

Answer (score 0):

Interprocess communication is typically defined as communication between multiple processes on a single machine. Distributed computing is multiple processes being distributed across a network and executed on desired host boxes. To me it makes sense to implement a desired interprocess communication in the same fashion as the distributed processes transmit their results back to the distributor/ host. That way a weaker machine continues to be able to process data while a more powerful box runs a greater load.